# How to tell if the window is being dragged in pygame

Tags: python, time, drag-and-drop, window, pygame

I am writing a game using pygame. If I drag the window with the mouse when the game is playing, then the game appears to pause, but when we release the mouse click the enemies have gone past all the walls and are making their merry way into the distance.

I am presuming this is because the loop continues to update the position of the sprites, but for some reason doesn't detect collisions between the walls and the enemies.

Anyway, I decided that I would just have pygame tell me if the window is being dragged. Then I figured just go pause the game.

Is there a function which can do this? Otherwise how would I do it?

If this doesn't get fixed, I can obviously just make fullscreen be used the entire time but I would prefer to fix this.

Comment: This doesn't look to me like the answer is to detect when someone drags the window. This looks like you should figure out what's happening when someone drags the window and make that stop happening. Your game shouldn't even notice when the window is being dragged.

Comment: I do know this response is a little late; but regarding the comment, I have been noticing the same effect, and I suspect that it is not because of the code continuing to run, but because, by using DeltaTime = clock.tick(30) to adjust for a slow computer, then this causes the looping to be delayed - but not the clock, hence this value increases to much larger proportions. I believe this because I noticed the same effect when making the game pause by stopping the loop - the same thing happened - but when I "wasted" a value by declaring the variable as clock.tick(30) 1 extra time, this stopped

Answer (score 1):

It's a little of a late answer, but I hope it might still be useful to anybody. If you print the FPS of your program in pygame, you will notice that they drop a lot when you drag a window or to put it this way round: your delta-time will be extremely high.

My main loop now returns every time, when the delta-time is above a certain value.

```
class MainProgram(object):
    def __init__(self, many_variables):
        # Much code here

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.dt = self.clock.tick(60) / 1000

    def mainloop(self):
        while self.running == True:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(60) / 1000
            if self.dt >= 0.05
                return
            # Rest of the program is only executed, if delta-time is below 0.05 sec
```

My FPS are limited to 60. At the same time I calculate the DT in seconds (pygame uses miliseconds!). If it raises too high resp. FPS drop too low (above 0.05s = 20FPS), I don't execute the main code anymore.

You can adjust these values to your needs. I figured out that for games a limit of 0.05 is about the best as the program should still be executable on older machines which can't reach the framerate (e.g. at 25FPS the DT is already 0.04s!).

Let me know if this was of any use for you :)

Comment: Fair enough. Setting a value to limit when we keep executing. I ended up just using fullscreen to avoid the issue altogether.